# Sentence start using ''of''

Tags: usage

is the below usage of ''of'' correct?

> Of all the components which lead a person to happiness, money plays the most pivotal role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely fine. The sentence could just as easily be written the other way around:

> Money plays the most pivotal role of all the components which lead a person to happiness.

Comment: can i replace ''of'' with ''among'' in your example sentence?

Comment: @LutfurRahman That sounds okay too.